# Make a link use all the space

Tags: html, css

I have a button class working like this :

```
<p class="button"><a href="#">Rejoindre</a></p>
```

The CSS is :

```
p.button
{
    background-color: #e74c3c;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}

.button a
{
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.button a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

How can I make the entire button (represented by the paragraph tag) a link instead of just the text ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put the link tag on the outside to make anything inside it be contained in the link:

```
<a href="#"><p class="button">Rejoindre</p></a>
```

However, you probably want to use something other than a `p` tag for your button, maybe a `button` element instead?

[More info on HTML buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button).

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: block` to the `.button a` ruleset.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/UvrKx/

Answer (score 1):

You can add `display:block;` to you anchor tag.

> display: block means that the element is displayed as a block, as
>   paragraphs and headers have always been. A block has some whitespace
>   above and below it and tolerates no HTML elements next to it, except
>   when ordered otherwise (by adding a float declaration to another
>   element, for instance).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/akx3p/

CSS:

```
p.button
{
    background-color: #e74c3c;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;

}

.button a
{
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
}

.button a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

`<p>` are block elements, meaning that they naturally are at `100%` width. If you just added `display: block;` to the anchor tag, you can make it behave the same way. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SkFJA/)
. That way allows you to get rid of the `p` tag all together.